# How to find OLE object location in crystal reports 8

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have few pictures on crystal report as OLE object.
is there any way to find the location, from where these pics inserted as OLE object.
I'm using old version CR 8

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well: choose `Edit->Links` from the menu. In the window that opens, all the OLE objects are listed. You mark one and below it shows:

```
Source: location of the object/file
Type: type of the object
Update: date
```

Comment: unfortunately link option is disabled :( in menu